# Group by packets of n hours

Tags: java, date, java-8, grouping

I have a Java POJO with a LocalDateTime field (controlDate) and an int (orders) field and others fields but not relevants to my issue.

I'm getting a list of this POJO from my database, for example :

```
controlDate                 orders
2018-10-07 23:26:00.000+02  5
2018-10-07 23:27:00.000+02  2
2018-10-07 18:33:00.000+02  8
2018-10-07 18:35:00.000+02  4
```

My end goal is to agregate the data by packet of n hours (and keep the oldest date as the agregated date), and by getting the average of the "orders" column

for example with a value of n = 2, i'd want to get something like :

```
controlDate                 orders
2018-10-07 23:26:00.000+02  3 (or 4, I don't really care about the rounding)
2018-10-07 18:33:00.000+02  6
```

I'm pretty sure that using Java 8 streams I can achieve that, probably using  Collectors.groupingBy, but I don't know how exactly I can achieve that....

Thanks for the help !

Comment: SQL has some pretty powerful grouping features (see `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`). This might be more appropriate and save you some Java coding.

Comment: Hi Dave, 

In fact my first approch was to do it in SQL and I succeded for a MySQL SGBD using a Hibernate native query. Now I have to migrate to PostgreSQL and so I have to write an all new native query.

I realized that it was not the best approch (what if tommorow i'm migrating to Oracle or another SGBD ?) 

That's why i'm trying to delegate the agregation part to my Java code to be independant of the SGBD.

I tried to look at Hibernate documentation but I didn't find anything that could achieve what i'm trying to do, except a native query

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, in keeping with the SO way, you should probably show us what code you have so far.

Comment: Those timestamps have an offset-from-UTC, meaning they represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. In that case, **`LocalDateTime` is the wrong class** to use, as that class cannot represent a moment. Use `OffsetDateTime` instead.

Comment: As far as i can see a stream won’t be well suited for grouping by the first time in the group as in your example result. If grouping by the whole hour is OK (as in the first answer posted so far), a stream is probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick:

```
class Delivery {
    LocalDateTime timestamp;
    Integer packages;

    public Delivery(LocalDateTime timestamp, Integer packages) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.packages = packages;
    }


    public Integer getPackages() {
        return packages;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return timestamp.toLocalDate();
    }

    public Integer getHour() {
        return timestamp.getHour();
    }

}

public class Calculate {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Stream<Delivery> deliveries = Stream.of(
                new Delivery(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 10, 7, 23, 26), 5),
                new Delivery(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 10, 7, 23, 27), 2),
                new Delivery(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 10, 7, 18, 33), 8),
                new Delivery(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 10, 7, 18, 35), 4)
        );

        deliveries.map(delivery -> {
            Map r = new HashMap();
            r.put(delivery.getHour(), delivery.getPackages());
            return r;
        }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.keySet().toArray()[0])).forEach((o, packages) -> {
            System.out.print(o + ":");
            Integer sum = (Integer) packages.stream().map(map -> map.get(o)).reduce(0, (a, b) -> (Integer) a + (Integer) b);
            long count = packages.stream().count();
            System.out.println(sum / count);
        });
    }
}
```

And you will get:

```
18:6
23:3
```

It is sorted by hours, so you can extend this solution to fit your needs.

Comment: For a large enough database result, this might throw OOM